# javascript : How to add a node/element to a specific-indexed location?

Tags: javascript

I have an element("p") which has say 10 children(10 div's).Based on user request i want to add a div under the "p" element to say 5th or 2ed position in the "p" Dom tree.

```
var div = document.createElement("div");  //Comment  Append
div.id="div"+divId;
div.className="div";
div.appendChild(document.createTextNode(divText));
var p = document.getElementById("comment");
length=p.childNodes.length;
```

Say p has a length of 15 and i want to add the div to the 13th position(adding it and NOT replacing it -- not replaceChild)

If i try traversing to the 13th position and do a `parentNode.appendChild` it gets appended(obviously) to the last position(15th position will be the new Div)

i want to add a div or any element to an Indexed location in a child list.

Please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looking for [insertBefore](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Node.insertBefore)

Answer (score 4):

Try `insertBefore`.

```
elementNode.insertBefore(new_node,existing_node)
```

The insertBefore() method inserts a new child node before an existing child node.

Comment: That did it.Dint know abt tat.Thanks